# Tap once to copy UITextView text substring

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview, uipasteboard

Say you've got a UITextView populated with a chunk of text. When a user taps on a word within the text I want the app to copy (retrieve the string) that word immediately. In your knowledge, is there any practical way to do this?

*Side note: I looked at UIPasteboard and all that but it is NOT what I'm looking for as it does not offer a one-tap solution. Central aim here is the concept of one-tap. I.e. Tap the text once and I retrieve the NSString.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you looked at UIPasteboard, but did you consider playing around with detecting touches and then setting the `[textView text]` yourself with `setValue:forPasteboardType:`?

Comment: I did have a look at setValue:forPasteboardType: but I don't get how that helps my problem?